# Do we keep hats from year to year?

Tags: discussion, winter-bash-2013

This is the first year that I pay attention to hats (I love hats!) and I wonder if I will keep my hats for next year?

Or will I start over with zero hats next year?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No, we don't keep our hats. Hats go back in the box when the Winterbash is over and they don't come out again. None of us who played last year kept any hats.

From the [FAQ](http://winterbash2013.stackexchange.com/faq):

> #### What happens after January 3rd?
>
> After January 3rd, the sites go back
>   to normal and all hats disappear. This is meant to be a fun
>   end-of-year celebration, not a permanent addition to the site.

It's only fair to you newcomers we didn't. :-)

Comment: Well it doesn't have to be fair, it's not that terrible to find out that people could sport many more hats that me and even ones that I could never get. But it's all just for fun so it doesn't matter ;)

Comment: Talking about fairness, some hats can be awarded only for high rep users, e.g. all hats related to reviews that low rep can only dream about. IMO it would be fair to give special hat next year for those with most hats this year (e.g. more than 40 hats when Winter Bash ends)

Answer (score 6):

You'll start with zero hats next year...in addition to it not being fair to newcomers if some users have a two-year head start, we change the hats (the illustrations, names, and triggers for awarding them) from year to year. The hats you can earn this year won't be available next year.

Comment: tempted to edit that to "a two-year hat start" ....

Comment: Well, there is at least one secret year which is the same as last year... :)

Comment: Things that are well-documented on meta and the blog aren't secret, @ShadowWizard. It's just unlisted on this year's site :) (Although technically that means the last sentence of this answer is incorrect.)

Comment: Yup, I was kind of referring to the last sentence. :-)