# How would you earn a hat after winter bash?

Tags: discussion, winter-bash

So, I've found in searches that hats are not saved after Winter Bash.
(Noted that one has a feature request to have a "hat archive" - which I think is a good idea just to be able to see what was previously earned).

[Do we keep hats from year to year?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/213110/do-we-keep-hats-from-year-to-year)

But one thing puzzles me. Multiple hats stated that they could be earned after Winter Bash was over. E.G. if a certain rep/vote was required, they could be earned if the post later got the required values. How can that occur when all the hats disappeared today? Or am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: "Multiple hats stated that they could be earned after Winter Bash was over." - where exactly did you see this?

Comment: @Oded maybe OP means hats that might become badges, e.g. [this discussion](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/247415/should-we-make-the-red-baron-hat-trigger-a-permanent-badge).

Comment: @Sha - dunno. OP doesn't mention anything about badges.

Comment: I think OP has just misunderstood something. Difficult to know where they got that idea from.

Comment: I can't find the wording anymore since all the Winter Bash stuff is gone. It's very possible I misunderstood. Maybe it was only talking about badges that had another time requirement other than being within Winter Bash itself.

Answer (score 9):

One (unstated) requirement for all hats are that the events/actions that lead to gaining a hat should all occur **during** the WinterBash event.

So... when WinterBash is over, none of the events/actions that would otherwise lead to a hat would fall under this requirement.

Comment: My question was pertaining to all actions occurring during Winter Bash - or, I guess all MAIN actions - and it just not being resolved until after. Regardless, I'm pretty sure I just misunderstood and I don't have access to the wording to reread it (or perhaps I would but don't know how to get there now that the obvious link is down).

Comment: http://winterbash2016.stackexchange.com/ is still up with all the hats and their descriptions.